# How to stop Mod4-P from switching the display?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, compiz

I use <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> very frequently to scroll backward in the command history, but I often mistype it as <kbd>Mod4-P</kbd>, which is bound to the switch display function.

I've searched around Keyboard shortcuts and CompizConfig, etc., but I couldn't find where <kbd>Mod4-P</kbd> is bound. What controls that?

Comment: If you're using the default Ubuntu interface, this is the sort of question that [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) is more likely to answer. If you ask there, please hyperlink the questions to each other.

Comment: Thank you, I have duplicate this question on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20113/how-to-stop-mod4-p-from-switching-the-display   Please close this, thanks.

Comment: Closing since it was crossposted ([sigh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the same key has bugged me both in Windows (inconveniently switching out of games at the wrong time), and Linux, I have levered off the Keycap itself so I will never accidentally hit it. However, for a less extreme remedy, you should be able to use xmodmap - (oldish) man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xmodmap.1.html

Comment: Damn! Both keys <kbd>Mod4</kbd> (which is mapped to <kbd>Win</kbd>) and <kbd>P</kbd> are so imporant, I CANT just lever them off!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's the same questions (and person asking), but as I was looking for the same answer I thought that crosslinking to solution can be useful for other people:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/20113/how-to-stop-mod4-p-from-switching-the-display/20273#20273

Comment: It was already done. See the comment to the question.